# How to sum values of children's children in Linq extensions

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have a structure of related tables like so:

[image]

Given the WorkReleaseDetail.WorkReleaseHeaderId, I want to get the aggregate sum of WorkOrderDetail.EstimatedQty grouped by WorkOrderDetail.ItemId using Linq extensions.

Since I need to group the lowest table, I thought I'd be able to .Where like:

`WorkOrderDetail.WorkOrderHeader.WorkReleaseDetail.WorkReleaseHeaderId == id`

But no dice as you get stopped at the OrderGroupDetails as it is an aggregation, your only options past that are .Sum, etc, which makes sense.

Then I want to do this (which should work):

```
var woDtlRepos = new Repository<WorkOrderDetail>();
var workOrdDtl = woDtlRepos.SearchFor(
x => x.WorkOrderHeader.FacilityId == intFacilityId
&& x.WorkOrderHeader.WorkReleaseDetails.WorkOrderHeaderId == intWorkReleaseId);

var workRlsNeeds = workOrdDtl
.GroupBy(group => new
    {
        group.ItemId
    }
)
.Select(result => new 
    { 
        ItemId = result.Key.ItemId,
        TotalQty = result.Sum(a => a.EstimatedQuantity)
    }
);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh...had an epiphany... use .Any()

```
var workOrdDtl = woDtlRepos.SearchFor(
x => x.WorkOrderHeader.FacilityId == intFacilityId
&& x.WorkOrderHeader.WorkReleaseDetails.Any(woRlsHdr => woRlsHdr.WorkReleaseHeaderId ==      intWorkReleaseId));
```